# Lennon or McCartney

Tags: the-beatles

OK, so I must ask this one. We all know Lennon's great great songs such as Come Together, Across the Universe and Ticket to Ride.

We also know McCartney's number 1 hits such as Here, There and Everywhere, Penny Lane and Yesterday.

There are also songs that it is not clear who wrote, like In my life.

And there's Here comes the sun, Something and My guitar gently weeps.

The question is... Lennon or McCartney?

Comment: Though I would say that _In my life_ most definitely sounds like a John Lennon song. He surely wrote most of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is easily available from multiple other sources.

Comment: What's the question?  Lennon or McCartney... what?

Comment: Is the question who is better?  We don't do opinion/quality-judgement questions here.  Maybe if the question was who had more hits, or even who was more influential.

Answer (score 8):

Here Comes the Sun, Something & While My Guitar Gently Weeps are all [George Harrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Harrison) compositions.

Comment: Here's a list for you : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_recorded_by_George_Harrison